# Why does my 2nd javascript promise call return the same value as the 1st?

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

Hi I am new to javascript and have recently been learning about promises. I am trying to wait on the result of a network call before moving forward with my logic. To do this I think I need a promise that waits on the network call's result. I have been practicing with promises and noticed some behavior I don't understand.

```
var mybool = false;

// Promise
var mypromise = new Promise(
    function (resolve, reject) {
        if (mybool) {
            var pvalue = 'PASS';
            resolve(pvalue);
        } else {
            var fvalue = new Error('FAIL');
            reject(fvalue);
        }
    }
);


// call promise
var callpromise = function () {
    mypromise
        .then(function (fulfilled) {
            // yay, you got a new phone
            console.log(fulfilled);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            // ops, mom don't buy it
            console.log(error.message);
        });
}

callpromise();
console.log('This will appear first since prev function call is still thinking');
mybool = true;
console.log(mybool);
callpromise();
```

So as you can see the var `mybool` determines the output of the promise function. when I run this program this is the output:

```
"This will appear first since prev function call is still thinking"
true
"FAIL"
"FAIL"
```

Can someone explain why even after flipping the `mybool` var the 2nd`callpromise()` is still outputting a value I would only expect from `mybool = false`?

Comment: As a sidenote to anyone else struggling with this issue for HTTP requests, the built in `XMLHttpRequest` has a easy to use async/sync toggle param you can flip instead of messing with your own custom promise chains.

```request.open('GET', 'https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/films', true)```
^ async
```request.open('GET', 'https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/films', false)```
^ synchronus (IE the thread wont continue until this HTTP request has passed/failed)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Promises don't get "called", they get created. You create `mypromise` once, before `callpromise` gets actually called. By the time, `mybool` is false. If you want to create a Promise at a specific point in your code, or if you want multiple promises, create the promise inside of a function.

Comment: Oh I see. thanks. Putting my promise in a function like ```function genPromise(){
    var mypromise = new Promise(
        function (resolve, reject) {
            if (mybool) {
                var pvalue = 'PASS';
                resolve(pvalue);
            } else {
                var fvalue = new Error('FAIL');
                reject(fvalue);
            }
        }
    );
    return mypromise
}```
fixed the issue.

Comment: I liked the "Promises don't get "called" part, that alone should help anyone who gets lost in the woods with promises.

Answer (score 1):

The function ("callback" or "handler" is these are often called) you specify as the first argument to the `then` function, will be called when the promise "resolves", and the argument to *that* function (the "callback", not `then`) is the value *you* yourself supplied as argument to the `resolve` call.

Meaning that in your example, `fulfilled` is `"PASS"` (the value of `pvalue` that you specify as argument to `resolve`). The name `fulfilled` doesn't seem like a good candidate here, perhaps due to how you understood (incorrectly) promises work. A fitting name for it would be `value`, or `pvalue` (the same thing you `resolve` the promise with).

But the crucial piece of puzzle you're missing is that every time you call `then` with some callback function, the callback function *will* execute if the promise is in the "resolved" state (meaning that `resolve` has already been called earlier).

So you can call `then` 1000 times, and you will get your callback invoked 1000 times, with that one and the same resolved ("promised" in loose terms) value.

Let's break down your example:

1. By the time the `var mypromise = ...;` statement is executed, the `mypromise` promise is created *and* resolved -- the `Promise` constructor immediately invokes the provided function (called "executor" in promise terms), and this executor function in your case immediately calls `resolve` which puts the promise in the "resolved" state.
2. `callpromise` is just a function, which, when executed, essentially causes the user agent to call the function provided as argument to `then` as soon as and if the `mypromise` promise is in "resolved" state, which it is already (see 1.)
3. You call `callpromise` twice, but the promise was already resolved even before the first call, and so the value of `mybool` is of absolutely no effect as far as the promised value is concerned -- the promise was already resolved once, and that's it.

Try to add a `console.log` call in the promise executor function (the one evaluating `mybool`) and observe how your promise is resolved *once*, before you even create the `callback` function.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest change to what you're doing is probably to pass `mybool` into your promise-creator, which as others have pointed out should be a function.

I'm also adding a counter, so that you can see the results which resolve/reject in a different order than their creation.

```js
var mypromise = function(mybool, counter) {
    return new Promise(
        function (resolve, reject) {
            if (mybool) {
                var pvalue = 'PASS-' + counter;
                resolve(pvalue);
            } else {
                var fvalue = new Error('FAIL-' + counter);
                reject(fvalue);
            }
        }
    )
}


// call promise
var callpromise = function (mybool, counter) {
    mypromise(mybool, counter)
        .then(function (fulfilled) {
            // yay, you got a new phone
            console.log(fulfilled);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            // ops, mom don't buy it
            console.log(error.message);
        });
}


callpromise(false, 1);
console.log('This will appear first since prev function call is still thinking');
callpromise(true, 2);
```